# missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed

Tags: r

In the following code

```
for (i in 1:length(Ejecsyes)){ 
 for (j in 1:length(Resultadosyes)) {
 if (table5[Ejecsyes[i],Resultadosyes[j]] > 5){ 

 if (table5[Ejecsyes[i],Resultadosyes[j]] < 0.9){table5[Ejecsyes[i],Resultadosyes[j]]<-0}
  else  { table5[Ejecsyes[i],Resultadosyes[j]]<-1}

}

}
}
```

I'm getting the following error, I think there's something wrong with the if-else and the outer if that contains it but can't find why

```
Error in if (table5[Ejecsyes[i], Resultadosyes[j]] > 5) { : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

Comment: Please follow [this guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `if(.)` ddoes not accept NA's.